# Zeppelin's Hive interpreter throws null pointer exception

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, bigdata

I am using zeppelin cloned from https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin.

Hive : version 1.2.1
Hive is configured in standalone mode, metastore_db is handled by Derby.

I have a properly set up Hive interpreter in a zeppelin notebook.

I have successfully created a table from the hive interpreter as follows

```
%hive
CREATE TABLE 30SEC(
id bigint,
obu_id varchar(100),
obu_make varchar(100),
)ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS TextFile
```

I successfully loaded data from a text file from my hdfs

```
%hive
load data 
inpath "/path/to/file"
into table 30sec
```

When I run queries without aggregate functions, it works fine,

[image]

But if queries contain aggregate functions, nullpointer exception is thrown by Hive interpreter

[image]

Please help me out if I missed out on any important configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bug was filed for this at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-629

The commit https://github.com/vgmartinez/incubator-zeppelin/commit/05fa23f8c5112b4e60d0ff1685565af31e5e8a44 fixed the issue.

Thanks to Zeppelin community for the quick action.

Answer (score 0):

When using aggregate functions , group by is required.
Please correct and try again

> select obu_id,count(1) fromm 30sec group by obu_id

Comment: Thanks yoga.. 
yeah I tried the correct query select obu_id,count(1) fromm 30sec group by obu_id, but the same null pointer exception is thrown.

I am suspecting the Derby metastore_db's capability of allowing only one connection at a time.

Comment: Just adding few more of my observations..

    * Created a table and inserted values into the table from Hive command line interpreter.

    * select query with aggregate functions seems to work just perfect.

So, the problem could be with the hive interpreter shipped with zeppelin package.

Comment: Thanks for the info.
I tested on the zeppelin packaged with HDP 2.3. it was working good.Please give a try if required.